# Universal links - how to match the at character?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I am currently adding universal links to my app. It generally works like a charm with the following `apple-app-site-association` file:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [{
      "appID": "...",
      "paths": [
        "/users/*",
        "/events/*",
        "/posts/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For short-linking purposes I would like to add links like `/@username`. But I cannot find a pattern that works for the at-sign. None of the following seems to work:

- `/@*`
- `/\@*`
- `/%40*`

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this, or is it currently impossible?

edit: Never mind. After troubleshooting for hours I noticed that the file is actually cached at Apple's CDN (`https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/www.domain.com`), so my changes could not work before Apple updated it.

Comment: Would the path have `@username` in it like `/users/@username/paulw11` or some actual user name like `/users/@paulw11`?

Comment: "NOT /nametag/*", "NOT /nametag", try to use this

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. It was a cache problem at Apple's CDN. Edited the post to reflect that.